# getCreatedAt() is not turning the date and time format

Tags: magento-1.7

I want a date and time format as this

```
$aWebOrder->OrderCreationDate  = '2012-11-08 12:00:00';
```

what i am doing is this:

```
$aWebOrder->OrderCreationDate    = $order->getCreatedAt();
```

I have tried to fix this but no success i just get a weird value which looks like is stamping only the seconds. Anyone experienced same issue? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually type of `created_at` column of `sales_flat_order` table is datetime, and $order->getCreatedAt() should return formatted datetime. 
You can try this one also:

```
$order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
```

Answer (score 6):

When I do the following:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getFirstItem();    
var_dump($order->getCreatedAt());
```

It returns:

```
string(19) "2013-03-28 12:31:17"
```

Perhaps, then, you have the following issues:

- `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` is subclassed and is providing a concrete `getCreatedAt` method (as opposed to the method being magic)
- Your data stored in the `created_at` column for the order in question actually has a Unix timestamp or some other data? This may hint at an illegal schema change.

To test if the model is subclassed, echo out `get_class($order)` - remove the rewrite if the model has been rewritten to diagnose.