# get the Order Created Date in excel sheet

Tags: magento-1.9

**Background** :

I tried below code to get order number in excel sheet, its working....

```
try{
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname') 
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do{
         //Tell the collection which page to load.
         $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
         $collection->load();
         foreach ($collection as $customer){
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();

  $newordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerArray['entity_id']);     
  $collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
  $firstItem = $newordercollection->getFirstItem();
  $orderID = $firstItem->getIncrementId();

            //write the collection array as a CSV.

            $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];          
            $customerREquiredArray['order id']= $orderID;
```

**Requirement & Issue** :

Now i need  **Order Created time** , so i followed [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/getcreatedat-is-not-turning-the-date-and-time-format) & tried below code :

```
$orderdate = $firstItem->getCreatedAtStoreDate()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
```

but got error as : **No date part in '' found.**

than i tried below one :

```
$orderdate = var_dump($newordercollection->getCreatedAt());
```

i got error as **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection::getCreatedAt()**

Comment: try this `$data = $newordercollection->getData(); $createdAt = $data['created_at']; var_dump($createdAt);`

Comment: @TinyDancer thanks, i got `Notice: Undefined index: created_at`

Comment: if u `var_dump($data)` what will it show?

Comment: well from ur code `$newordercollection` is set of collection of order model, you should loop it to get `created_at` value

Comment: @TinyDancer sorry, it showing lot : `array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> array(141) { ["entity_id"]=> string(3) "115" ["state"]=> string(10) "processing" ["status"]=> string(10) "processing" ["coupon_code"]=> NULL ["protect_code"]=> string(6) "cba3f3" ["shipping_description"]=> string(20) "Free Shipping - Free`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80373/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-tiny-dancer).

Comment: Thanks a lot @TinyDancer , its working, you can post an answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$newordercollection` is set of order model collections, so you need to loop it first:

```
foreach($newordercollection as $order){
 $createdAts[] = $order->getCreatedAt();
}
```

if you want to get the first item created at from the collection:

```
$createdAt = $newordercollection->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();
```